# Can you create flashcards in the Kindle device?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, kindle-app

I know there are some ways to *import* flashcards to your kindle, but does the kindle paperwhite allow you to create them right in the device?

Just like the kindle app for android does.

Comment: hmm, can you create the flashcards through a web interface?  but, yes, directly on the kindle would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Well I bought my Kindle Paperwhite so now I can answer my own question: No, you can't create flashcards with it.

Still it's a great device and a great investment to your reading hobby.